# Reorganize data in excel (possibly using vlookup and match?)

Tags: excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have an excel sheet (CSV, apparently compiled from an SQL database) with three columns of data collected from a survey of students:

- **A1/User_ID**: numeric value from 1 to 913. Each value is repeated for each entry associated to that number (e.g., if a student only answered 3 questions, then her number will only appear 3 times).
- **B1/Question_ID**: alphanumeric codes such as q01, q01a, ... q35c, which correspond to the questions on the survey. Each value is repeated for each student who answered each particular question (e.g., if 400 students answered q01, then q01 appears 400 times in this column).
- **C1/Comment**: what the students actually entered as answers to each question (mostly strings of text).

I want to organize the data so that A1 corresponds to User_ID and each following column corresponds to each of the questions on the survey (B1 to p01, C1 to p01a, D1 to p01b, etc); having each answer under the appropriate column, and unanswered questions as blanks or N/A's. I have been trying different tutorials using pivot tables and formulas such as vlookup, two-dimensional lookups, index, match, and some nesting among these, with no results as of yet. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the combination of User_ID and Question_ID unique? I.e. can each student only answer each question once?

Comment: @Captain: yes, each student can only answer each question once.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to deal with a compound-key lookup in this case would be to make a dummy column with the new key value. E.g. insert a new column A and use something like (in A2) `=B2&"§"&C2` - this will give you a user§question key.

In your reorganized sheet, with users down the side and questions along the top you can then enter the lookup formula. The key we want to lookup is the user in column A and the question in row 1 - so an example in B2 this key would be: `$A2&"§"&B$1` - note that we are using the absolute row/column using `$` so that when we copy & paste the formula we get it updating correctly.

Then, with this new key, we can do a simple lookup. In B2: `=VLOOKUP($A2&"§"&B$1,csv!$A:$A,4,FALSE)` - so looking up our compound key in our new column A of the `csv` sheet, returning the value in column 4 (comment), and doing an exact match (`FALSE`)

**UPDATE** You might also want to wrap this in an `IFERROR(...,"")` so that you get the blank if it wasn't found, rather than the lookup error.

As I said, the compound-key "dummy column" approach is easiest - but there are other ways if you don't want that extra column.

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed, step by step input. I tried it just as you explained and keep getting a REF error for combinations that actually have data in the D(Comment) column, and N/A for combinations that don't. I even renamed the sheet to "csv" to match the example exactly, in case that was getting in the way (this is without the IFERROR part). For the IFERROR part, this is what I tried: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2&"§"&B$1,csv!$A:$A,4,FALSE),"") and Excel is not taking it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: after playing around with the formula i see that the REF error can be fixed if the table array is expanded to $A:$D (instead of $A:$A as in the original example). Thanks a ton for the help!